# change the link value of datagridviewlink cell

Tags: c#

I am using datagridview with datagridviewlinkcell . 
I want to give the functionality to edit/Update. 
If I click "Edit" link, Link should be automatically changed to "Update".
I have done some code. But it is not working.

```
if (dgvGearRatios[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewLinkCell))
{
    dgvGearRatios.ReadOnly = false;
    DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = (DataGridViewLinkCell)dgvGearRatios[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if(linkCell.FormattedValue.ToString() == "Edit")
    {
        linkCell.Value = "Update";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Explain what is not working, exception, crash, or the event simply doesn't fire?

Comment: linkcell.value is not changing . It remains "Edit"

Comment: which event do you subscribe to? `CellContentClick` or `CellClick`, or something else?

Comment: I have used cellclick event

Comment: have you try debugging? add some breakpoints inside this method, if the code runs smoothly, the value should be updated; if the code runs unexpectedly, for example, the `if` statements evaluated to false, or the type casting is unsuccessful, or _the code was not run at all_, fix the bug.

Comment: I have done everything , added breakpoints but its not happening

Comment: sounds like the cellclick event is not fired, how do you subscribe to the cellclick event? Find `dgvGearRatios.CellClick` in your code, check if it is subscribed to correctly.

Comment: It is subscribed correctly . just let me know that code is correct or is there any problem in code

Comment: the code is working on my test project. at which line the code it breaks? does it run to the last line?

Comment: Code does not break. But "linkCell.Value" is not updating. it always remains "Edit" even-though code run through linkCell.value = "Update"

Comment: could you post your code (compress as .zip) to google drive and let me have a look?

Comment: Ok I will let you know